# how to get xml node value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to xslt programming and I need to do xml to xml transformation using xslt.

following is my xml document

```
<investments>
  <item type="stock" exch="nyse"   symbol="ZCXM" company="zacx corp"
        price="28.875"/>
  <item type="stock" exch="nasdaq" symbol="ZFFX" company="zaffymat inc"
        price="92.250"/>
  <item type="stock" exch="nasdaq" symbol="ZYSZ" company="zysmergy inc"
        price="20.313"/>
</investments>
```

I need to change this xml structure as follows

```
<portfolio>
  <stock exchange="nyse">
    <name>zacx corp</name>
    <symbol>ZCXM</symbol>
    <price>28.875</price>
  </stock>
  <stock exchange="nasdaq">
    <name>zaffymat inc</name>
    <symbol>ZFFX</symbol>
    <price>92.250</price>
  </stock>
  <stock exchange="nasdaq">
    <name>zysmergy inc</name>
    <symbol>ZYSZ</symbol>
    <price>20.313</price>
  </stock>
</portfolio>
```

so, I wrote the xsl document as follows,

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <portfolio>
    <xsl:for-each select="investments/item[@type='stock']">
      <stock>
        <xsl:attribute name="exchange">
            <xsl:value-of select="@exch"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="@company"/></name>
        <symbol><xsl:value-of select="@symbol"/></symbol>
        <price><xsl:value-of select="@price"/></price>
      </stock>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </portfolio>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There are no cording errors, but xslt document is not getting the xml node. in xml to html transformation I can simply link xml and xslt using `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>` and get xml nodes.
But i'm confused how can I link xml and xslt when doing the xml to xml transformation.

any suggestions how I can do it?

Comment: How exactly are you "*doing the xml to xml transformation*"?

Comment: i'm using oxeygen editor and debug using saxon to get output

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the problem you describe. The XSLT stylesheet above, when applied to your example input,  produces the expected result.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, I simply want to know to link xml and xsl files when we are doing the xml to xml transformation. I really appreciate your help

Comment: You are not supposed to "link" the files internally (although I believe you *could* do so, if you really wanted). Just give your processor paths to both source and stylesheet when you initiate the transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Thanks. appreciate your heap.